# ADC Set up for pic18f1xk22 in C

Tags: c, embedded, pic18

Beginner trying to learn ADC setup, but unfortunately most examples online are for other pic18 models, and I don't have the adc.h definition as a resource. (Or else not for C code.) Don't want to be spoon-fed an answer really, but if anyone could suggest some great walk-throughs, online resources, etc. I'd really appreciate it, thanks!

Also any help with this pseudo-code I've written would be great. Likely to have errors... No clue if I'm on the right track or not.

```
//configure port
    //disable pin output driver (TRIS) - same thing as clear?
    //configure pin as analog
//configure adc module
    //set ADC conversion clock
    // configure voltage reference
    //select adc input channel
        //CH0-CH12 of ADCON0
    // select result format
        //select data format using the ADFM bit of the ADCON1 register                                                 
           //select aquisition delay  
    // turn on ADC module
        //enable A/D converter by setting the ADON bit of the ADCON0 register                                                     
//start conversion by setting GODONE bit of ADCON0 register
    //GODONE = 1;

// read ADC result
    //read the ADRESH and ADRESL registers
//clear the adc interrupt flag (optional)
```

Comment: The microchip data sheet has all the SFR locations and the ADC only has 8 registers - you can easily do your own 'adc.h'. The data sheet also has an assembler example that should be fairly easy to implement in C. Why not try some code and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect yet, but got most of it figured out. Rest shouldn't be too difficult.. Just need to implement the interrupt now mostly.

```
    TRISc = 0x01; // disable tri-state    
    ANSEL = 0xFF;//setting to analog
    ADCON1 = 0x00;//Voltage References Set
    ADCON2 = 0x00;// left justified ADFM, set Acquisition Time and Conversion Clock
    ADCON0 = 0x11;// Analog Channel Select, GODONE set, Enable ADC

    //TODO:interrupt ADIF bit in the PIR1 register
    ADIF = 0;
    ADIE = 1;
    GODONE = 1;
    while(GODONE) {};

    adcValue = ADRESH;
    adcValue <<= 8;
    adcValue |= ADRESL;

    while(1){}
```